# In the windows python console, how to make Tab = four spaces?

Tags: python, windows

Hello I would like that when I am in the python
console tabbing will give me four spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to do this?

Comment: if i want to cut and paste from the console window i won't have to replace the tabs later.

Comment: I got tired of pressing space four times for a def and four x 2 spaces for a def in a class in Console.

Comment: You don't have to press explicitly 4 spaces. 1 space will do the indent for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download and install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)
2. Write this script:

   ```
   SetTitleMatchMode 2
   #IfWinActive python
   tab::
   Send, {SPACE}
   Send, {SPACE}
   Send, {SPACE}
   Send, {SPACE}
   ```

Save it as tab-to-space.ahk, and doubleclick on the file.

Note: you might have to captalize "Python" to match your window tite. Or you can have "yhton" and it will match Jython too.

Comment: Won't this change _every_ Tab you _ever_ type into 4 spaces? If so, won't that screw up a lot of other things?

Comment: ++ for AHK. Love this little tool!